# Playing multiple sounds in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I am developing a HTML5 game for Facebook. I have the following HTML code:

```
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-0">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-1">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-2">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-3">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-4">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
<audio style="visibility: hidden;" controls="controls" id="sound-5">
    <source src="sound/sound_new.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
    <source src="sound/sound_new.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
```

And the following Javascript that starts the sounds:

```
if (this.hitFlag > 6) this.hitFlag = 1;
var soundElem = document.getElementById('sound-' + (this.soundFlag % 6) + '0' );
soundElem.play();
```

Each click of the mouse triggers a sound event. The problem is with Chrome where after dozen of clicks the sounds disappear or start playing with quite a big delay(a dozen of seconds).
But there is no problem when playing in FF or Opera.

Comment: Chrome has fixed a lot of its <audio> latency bugs, but can you log this as an issue (new.crbug.com) and attach the test case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely a bug, but I think it has to do with the actual element and not the sound playing portion. You can easily get around this by preloading your audio, instantiating a new audio object for each playing of a sound, then finally checking the sound objects at each tick to determine whether or not they've finished playing so you can clean up memory.

Preloading is, of course, something like:

```
var _mySnd = new Audio('my/snd/file/is/here.mp3');
```

Instantiating is like:

```
var _sndCollection = [];
var n = _sndCollection.length;

_sndCollection[n] = new Audio();
_sndCollection[n].src = _mySnd.src;
_sndCollection[n].play();
```

And the cleanup check would be:

```
for (var i = 0; i < _sndCollection.length; i++)
{
    if (_sndCollection[i].currentTime >= _sndCollection[i].duration)
    {
        _sndCollection.splice(i, 1);
        i--;
    }
}
```

I use something like this in my own HTML5 game engine, and it's worked perfectly thus far.

Comment: Thank you @ceprovence I will try your code right after Christmas! Happy Christmas to you!

Comment: This (or something like this) appears to work, but doesn't it box you into one file type, such as .mp3 in your sample code? The <audio> tag cleanly supports multiple file types, and when I was working with sound a year ago I found that I needed .mp3 and .ogg and .wav to cover all browsers.

Comment: Follow-up: using your system I'm getting sound lags, as if the preload of _mySnd does not extend to _sndCollection[n].