# mp3 audio file is not working on tablet

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tablet

I am running mp3 audio files one on click on other click on the same page i want my previous mp3 file to run along with the new one. but all mp3 files are working perfectly on browsers with windows machine, but when i open browser in a tablet its not working properly.

second mp3 stops when i click to run another audio, i want to run both.

please give me suggestion.

this is what i am using...

```
<audio autoplay="true" type="audio/mpeg" src="voices/letsdressuptoplay.mp3" id="music4"  >     </audio>
```

thanks.

Comment: What OS is the tablet running on?

Comment: sir its andriod 4.1.2 version , android.

Comment: this problem is with world browser...and no sound is working on chrome(updated) on tablet.

Comment: It seems you have the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606393/playing-multiple-sounds-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

We cannot run multiple mp3 or videos in any browser on devices like iPad. There is restriction in tablets.
As an application you can run multiple mp3.

Comment: but its running on browser.